# Our relay had some downtime due to some network repairs and changes (including an IP change)

Tags: relays

Lightning.

I've used this opportunity to upgrade our installation to 0.3.0.8, and I've increased our provided burst rate to 4Mb/sec.

Accordingly, how long will it be before Tor settles down to this new IP address and starts running the former level of traffic through it? Just trying to understand how all this works.

Fingerprint of our installation is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It takes an hour to re-integrate into the same rates - I've managed/serviced my relay many times, in one hour it usually goes back. Sometimes it was even faster. If you have had a `Guard` flag - well, this can return in days. `HSDir` and `V2Dir` returned in a day ( in 24 hours ). There're no "standard-defined" timings, it's a question of network consensus. First, a `Valid` and `Fast` flags are coming back - then network re-evaluates your relay and here you go

Comment: `HSDir` returns after 4 days. There are absolutely standard defined timings, the standard *is* the consensus or what is explicitly specified in the dir-spec.

Comment: @canonizingironize in my case twice after a 20-30 minutes of downtime HSDir has returned in 20 hours: offline was around a 1am and by the midnight of the very same day it was back in place... It happened around a year+ ago, now I have changed the management and service procedure, so downtime lasts no longer than 5 minutes and flags are not even dropping